# Invalid instruction operand when using punpcklwd with MMWORD PTR 64-bit memory operand

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, masm, mmx

Currently working on some old assembly code, and MASM errors out with this line.

```
punpcklwd MM3, MMWORD PTR [8+EBP+ECX*2]
```

Gives me: error A2070: invalid instruction operands

But, this should be valid, right? The disassembled code from a compiled copy is basically identical to this.

Also, according to this PDF, this is how it's supposed to be written... https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/mmx-app-mpeg1-audio-kernels-140701.pdf

Comment: Are you building for x64?

Comment: No, for x86, with MMX instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The memory source operand is 32-bit DWORD, not MMWORD or QWORD.
See [Intel's asm manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpcklbw:punpcklwd:punpckldq:punpcklqdq):

```
PUNPCKLWD mm, mm/m32                MMX
PUNPCKLWD xmm1, xmm2/m128           SSE2
```

Unfortunately, the same is not true for the XMM version: it does count as a 128-bit load, faulting if it extends into an unmapped page or is misaligned.

The Description section backs this up:

> When the source data comes from a 128-bit memory operand, an implementation may fetch only the appropriate 64 bits; however, alignment to a 16-byte boundary and normal segment checking will still be enforced.

> Legacy SSE versions 64-bit operand: The source operand can be an MMX technology register **or a 32-bit memory location**. The destination operand is an MMX technology register.

The 128-bit behaviour is one of many dumb design decisions in SSE1/SSE2.  I wonder if Pentium 4 had limitations on store-forwarding or something that would have somehow made it less efficient in that first-gen implementation to be like a `movq` load.  There is `movhps xmm3, qword ptr [ecx]` to load into the upper half to replace `punpcklqdq`, but you just need a separate `movq` for narrower interleaves.

The MMX behaviour of only taking an operand of the width it uses is the sensible one.  I don't know why the Intel doc you linked uses MMWORD with it; maybe some assemblers accepted that at the time.  It does make sense that current MASM rejects it, but that could have gone either way.

---

Do note that [`punpckHwd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpckhbw:punpckhwd:punpckhdq:punpckhqdq) and so on want a register-width memory operand, I guess so it more closely matches the register source version, e.g. `punpckhwd mm3, mm0` could be replaced with `movq [esi], mm0` / `punpckhwd mm3, [esi]` and run the same, rather than needing `[esi+4]`.

That also let them build HW that just feeds a 64-bit load to the shuffle unit, without needing a broadcast or shifted load to get the data at the right place for input to the ALU.  Modern Intel load ports can do broadcast loads (e.g. `movddup` or `vbroadcastss` with a memory source run as a single uop for a load port, no ALU involved), but that's something much more recent than P5 Pentium.

> When the source data comes from a 64-bit memory operand, the full 64-bit operand is accessed from memory, but the instruction uses only the high-order 32 bits. When the source data comes from a 128-bit memory operand, an implementation may fetch only the appropriate 64 bits; however, alignment to a 16-byte boundary and normal segment checking will still be enforced.

---

#### Omit the DWORD / MMWORD PTR entirely

And BTW,  `punpcklwd MM3, [8+EBP+ECX*2]` should assemble just fine with most Intel-syntax assemblers, including MASM as well as NASM and GAS with `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  The register destination (along with the mnemonic) implies the size of the memory operand.

GNU Binutils `objdump -drwC -Mintel` agrees with Intel's manual that it's a 32-bit memory operand.  I assume MASM would want the same syntax.

```
 8049000:       0f 61 5c 4d 08          punpcklwd mm3,DWORD PTR [ebp+ecx*2+0x8]
 8049005:       66 0f 61 5c 4d 08       punpcklwd xmm3,XMMWORD PTR [ebp+ecx*2+0x8]
```